# Mod_Rewrite: Rewrite URL to index.php but redirect index.php to root

Tags: mod-rewrite

I want to rewrite requests to use index.php which is pretty standard and works.

The problem is that there are old and now invalid links which include the index.php and I want to redirect them to the root url of my site.

Potential duplicates include: [Rewrite URL to index.php but avoid index.php in the URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2938699/rewrite-url-to-index-php-but-avoid-index-php-in-the-url), but the answers mentioned don't work for me.

```
RewriteEngine on

# This results in a redirect loop
#Redirect 301 /index.php http://domain.com

# This gets me a 500 error
# RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /index\.php/?([^ ]*)
# RewriteRule ^index\.php/?(.*) / [L,R=301]

# Push www traffic to base domain.  <<= Works
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^domain.com$ [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]

# Final rewrite to include index.php   <<= Works
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule /?([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/?$ index.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]
```

The url: http://domain.com/index.php/component/fsf/?view=faq, should be invalid and it should return a 404 error but because of my current rewrite rules, a site visitor will see the main page.  I want to redirect this with a 301 to the main page so it can be dropped from search indexes.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your `THE_REQUEST` rule to

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /index\.php(/.*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /? [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Closer, it rewrote the specific example too [dbfront.com/?view=faq] and did not cause any further issues.  I actually want the URL stripped of any garbage.